# Differential of a function

Tags: calculus

In simple words, the differential of a function is no more than the value of the function (for a given value of x), calculated on the tangent on the curve instead. But calculating the value of the function on the tangent does not give me an accurate value of the function as it gives me when calculating the curve .........
So: why do I need to calculate this differential?
Could you help me understand?

Comment: The differential is more like "the slope of the tangent". How fast it is growing. For example, the differential of the position (w.r.t time) is the velocity!